# Distribution of for loop iterations over triangular matrix with MPI

Tags: for-loop, optimization, fortran, mpi

I have a program in MPI and openMP that computes some interactions between particles. In this process, I have a symmetric matrix A of possible interactions between particles i and j over which I have to loop through. So I split the n x n matrix in columns of the same size, and send each section to be dealt with by a different MPI process. Then indivudual columns of the splits get dealt with locally by openMP. The fortran loop works like this:

1. the first loop goes through the different columns in the split;
2. then it looks at the kd tree for this given column, and keeps only the relevant interactions;
3. then it loops over these interaction and if the index associated with this interaction is not in the lower triangular matrix (exploit the symmetry that $A_{ij}=A_{ji}$) then it cycles.

Here is some pseudo code to understand:

```
iter_per_rank = n/n_ranks

if ( mod(n, n_ranks) > 0 ) then
    iter_per_rank = iter_per_rank + 1
end if

first_iter = rank * iter_per_rank + 1
last_iter = first_iter + iter_per_rank - 1

!$omp parallel do schedule(guided) &
!$omp private(i,j,idx)
!$omp reduction(+:...)
do i = last_iter, first_iter, -1
    idx = search%kdtree(array(i))
    do k = 1, size(idx%i%values) -1
        j = idx%i%values(k+1)

        if (i .ge. j) then
            cycle
        end if

        [...]

    end do
end do
!$omp end parallel do

call mpi_comms(...)
```

The problem I have is that when this code runs, not all cores are being used all the time because of this crude (equal) separation of the matrix A. This would be fine if I was to go through all indices, but since I have this kd-tree and the symmetry of the matrix, these are actually biasing the initial separation such that the columns in the last splits are finishing their part of the computation much earlier then the first one.

My question is therefore: does a better split (than a uniform one) can be made if given a estimation of the maximum number of relevant indices in the first column? I am asking from the point of view of MPI balancing.

I have in mind something were the first split would be small and then steadily increasing towards larger splits as we go from process to process.
[image: Here is a plot of the usage of the CPUs for 256 CPUs on 4 nodes. We see that it varies wildly.]

I did not try anything yet, I am hoping someone has a bright idea on how to do this.

Comment: Is there a reason you are manually, statically dividing the columns between the threads? Why not use a !$OMP worksharing directive and dynamic load balancing? Or id your pseudo-code misleading? Real code, especially a [minim, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), would be *much* more helpful.

Comment: Or actually !$OMP tasks might be a good fit here. But without real code its hard to tell.

Comment: No no, I am using mpi to divide the process, then openmp deals with the rest. I am using: !$omp parallel do schedule(guided) for the loop, I don't think this is the issue

Comment: If OpenMP is not the issue and if this is only a problem of unbalanced workload between MPI processes, then you'd better remove the openmp tag and make clearer that your question is about balancing the MPI workload

Comment: What does prevent you from splitting the matrix into uneven number of columns between the MPI processes ?

Comment: @Pieru seems on the mark to me. Why are you even bothering to distract us with lots of irrelevant OpenMP code if it's not the issue, while not showing any of the MPI level code where the fix will need to be?

Comment: No, you are confused, read the title. What I am asking about is how to distribute the indexing in mpi processes so that this is optimized. So how should the variables `iter_per_ranks` `first_iter` and `last_iter` be?

Comment: @PierU that is what I want to do. But is there an optimal way to split the columns for a sparse triangular matrix, knowing the average element per column?

Comment: @Sogapi People are confused because the title is about MPI BUT the posted code is only about OpenMP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, the `schedule(dynamic)` clause is the solution to imbalanced iterations:

```
!$OMP PARALLEL DO SCHEDULE(DYNAMIC)
do i = n, 1, -1
   ...
end do
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
```

In practice, however, the dynamic scheduling is more costly than the static default scheduling, and depending on the actual workload it can be more or less efficient. If you have a compiler that implement the latest OpenMP features you can test the `nonmonotonic` modifier, which is is supposed to get the best of the static and dynamic scheduling: `SCHEDULE(NONMONOTONIC:DYNAMIC)`. You can also play with the chunk size (1 by default, but larger chunks can help... or not): `SCHEDULE(DYNAMIC,10)`

Tasks is another approach to solve this problem, but again they can more or less efficient depending on the actual computations:

```
!$OMP PARALLEL 
!$OMP SINGLE
do i = n, 1, -1
   !$OMP TASK
   ...
   !$OMP END TASK
end do
!$OMP END SINGLE
!$OMP END PARALLEL
```

With tasks, you have to be especially careful about the shared/private status of the variables, but to go further some real code would be needed.

---

**Edit: Dividing the work between the MPI processes**

If the matrix is n*n, upper triangular, and sparse.

- The number of non-zero elements in a column is proportionnal to the column number `k`; let's say it's equal to k, it won't change the results
- The total number of elements in a upper triangular matrix is `ntot = n*(n+1)/2`
- The number of elements from the column 1 to k is `k*(k+1)/2`
- You want to have a balanced number of elements between p MPI processes, that is `ntot/p`
- Let's say the rank r (numbered from 1 to p) processes the columns `k(r-1)+1:k(r)`, then we have:

  - `k(0) = 0`
  - `k(p) = n`
  - `k(r)*(k(r)+1)/2 - k(r-1)*(k(r-1)+1)/2 ~= ntot/p`

This is an implicit reccurence relation: once you know `k(r-1)` you get `k(r)` by solving a degree 2 equation (and if you neglect the `+1` terms it gets straightforward). You have to take care of the roundings to integers, which means the solutions are only approximate.

Once you get `k(r-1)` the equation to solve is
`k(r) * (k(r)+1) = x`
with `x = 2*ntot/p +  k(r-1) * (k(r-1)+1)/2`
That is
`k(r)^2 + k(r) - x = 0`
The determinant is `D = 1 + 4*x`
Hence the solution: `k(r) = (sqrt(D) - 1)/2`
And you round it to the nearest integer.

Code:

```
real :: x
integer :: n, p, nprev
integer, allocatable :: k(:)
allocate( k(0:p) )
ntot = n * (n+1) / 2
k(0) = 0
do r = 1, p
   nprev = k(r-1) * (k(r-1)+1) / 2
   x = 2.0*(ntot/real(p) + nprev)
   k(r) = round( 0.5*sqrt(1.0+4.0*x)-0.5 )
end do
```

Adaptive version, which ensures that `k(p) = n` :

```
k(0) = 0
do r = 1, p
   nprev = k(r-1) * (k(r-1)+1) / 2
   x = 2*(ntot - nprev) / real(p-r+1) + 2*nprev
   k(r) = round( 0.5*sqrt(1.0+4.0*x)-0.5 )
end do
```

Comment: I am using !$omp parallel do schedule(guided) for the loop but that is limited by the initial separation of the matrix by mpi no? Let's say I have a 6x6 triangular matrix with 2 mpi processes that each deal with 3 columns. The first process would have to deal with potentially 5+4+3=12 iterations (handled by opm) and the second one would have to deal with only 2+1=3 iterations.

Comment: What *is* the size of your matrix? Roughly? See without a complete, runnable code we just have to keep guessing

Comment: This answer is fine from an OpenMP point of view, but what @Sogapi is saying is that his problem isn't in the OpenMP at all...

Comment: My matrix is roughly of size 5000 x 5000

Comment: @JimCownie Right, but why didn't he post the MPI part of the code, then ?

Comment: I've completed the answer about how to divide a triangular matrix into balanced numbers of elements.

Comment: @PierU neat! Can I ask: what does the `j` stands for in your second version?

Comment: Interestingly, when doing that, the performance of the code worsens...

Comment: typo: it was `r`, not `j`... Without the full code it's difficult to comment on the performances.

Comment: @PierU "Why didn't he post the MPI code?". I quite agree, this whole thing is close to the classic "I have a problem I'm not describing, but here's a broken solution, please fix it for me?" question. The best  solution is often found in solving the issue  a few "Why?"s up the tree...